# Save OpenVPN username/password in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, debian, openvpn

I want to let OpenVPN find my username and password from a file, so that I do not have to enter these every time I connect.
I'm using Backbox linux (Debian/Ubuntu).

```
uname -a
Linux pop 3.19.0-39-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 10:00:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

OpenVPN seems to be installed with saved passwords enabled:

```
openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_crypto=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_eurephia=yes enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_http_proxy=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_lzo_stub=no enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=yes enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no enable_socks=yes enable_ssl=yes enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_ifconfig_path=/sbin/ifconfig with_iproute_path=/sbin/ip with_mem_check=no with_plugindir='${prefix}/lib/openvpn' with_route_path=/sbin/route with_sysroot=no
```

In my .ovpn file I have the following line:

```
auth-user-pass /path/to/pass.txt
```

where `pass.txt` contains 2 lines (my username and password).
I connect using `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`. Each time I try to connect, the network manager icon rotates for about 40 seconds, then I am finally asked to enter my password.
Why can't I connect automatically (without having to type my password)?

EDIT: It seems I do not have to enter my password when I make the connection from the command line, suggesting the problem is with network-manager.

Comment: As per the documentation for `auth-user-pass`, `The server configuration must specify an --auth-user-pass-verify script to verify the username/password provided by the client. `. Do you have that?

Comment: No I don't. Could you provide a link to an example script? Thx.